# How to get the index of particular JTextfield?

Tags: java, swing

Say I have an  array of Jtextfields (for e.g JTextfield[10]). I added them to the frame. Now user input  text in textfields randomly for e.g user first input in textfield of index 5 then 9 then 2 and so on. Not necessarily filling all the textfields.

My question is how to get the index of the text field and print the index simultaneously as user input the text meaning that if the user input in text field with index 5 I should be able to get the index 5 and then if texfield with index 9 is filled 9 is printed and so on.

Comment: Have a look at `FocusListener`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `FocusListener` to every `JTextField` in your Array, you can achieve your goal. Check out something like this,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class indexTest extends JFrame {

    public indexTest() {
        super();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setSize(400, 250); // setting frame size

        JTextField jTextField1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField jTextField2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField jTextField3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField jTextField4 = new JTextField();
        JTextField jTextField5 = new JTextField();

        TextFocusListener focusListener = new TextFocusListener();

        jTextField1.addFocusListener(focusListener);
        jTextField2.addFocusListener(focusListener);
        jTextField3.addFocusListener(focusListener);
        jTextField4.addFocusListener(focusListener);
        jTextField5.addFocusListener(focusListener);

        JTextField jTextField[] = new JTextField[]{jTextField1, jTextField2, jTextField3, jTextField4, jTextField5};
        int posY = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < jTextField.length; i++) {
            JTextField textField = jTextField[i];
            textField.setName("textField " + i);
            textField.setBounds(10, posY, 100, 15);
            getContentPane().add(textField);
            posY += 20;
        }
    }
}

class TextFocusListener implements FocusListener {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println(((JTextField) e.getSource()).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        //todo your user logic goes here // Ex: check user actually entered value or not
    }
}

class RunFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            indexTest indexTest = new indexTest();
            indexTest.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A better solution would have been to use an `ArrayList`, then you could use `indexOf` to find the specific field or make use of the `actionCommand` or `clientProperty` properties to seed some kind of identifier into the field - just saying. Also `textField.setBounds` is completely pointless and is presenting a bad idea to a novice developer

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are suggesting to use layouts instead of   absolute positioning ?

Comment: I never suggest using anything less, in fact you are, which makes the `setBounds` even more pointless

Comment: I did something like this.               I took   JTextfield[] jtextfield = new JTextfielsd[10];
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
       Jtextfield source = (Jtextfield)e.getSource();                                                       for (int i=0;i<10;++i){                                                      if(source==jtextfield[i]){                                            System.out.println(i);}}
    }.                                                                                  But the if conditon here never becomes true .Can you please tell me why. Thanks one aagain

Comment: @Joey why do you need something like this `if(source==jtextfield[i])` anyway this should return true for one time thorough the iteration.

Comment: Becasue i need the value of i . I want to further use this textfield and its data for other purpose. Thats why. I have read about it in some example so i tried it.

Comment: @Joey therefore simply use `((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText()` no need to iterate through the array ,  `e.getSource()` will return the same JTextField